# At what point in the run-time process does IIS compress output?

Tags: iis, compression, action-filter

I recently tried to integrate [WebMarkupMin](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki), a run-time html minification library, into my site (C#, IIS 8, MVC 4). We have IIS compression enabled. I discovered that IIS actually compresses the action filter output stream, which means when I try to minify my html in an action filter, I am trying to minify already compressed content.

**Question:** At what point in the run-time process does IIS compress output? Is there any way to use mvc action filters to modify html ouptut without disabling IIS compression?

Answer (score 1):

The IIS dynamic compression for ASP MVC output runs pretty late in the pipeline. In my test it was No. 315 out of 349 pipeline items and after all the asp.net modules ran.

To see the order of the executed modules in the IIS pipeline, set up Failed Request tracing (FREB) for your site and review the logs.

I would say there is no way in your MVC action filter to tell the compression module not to compress.

But you can turn compression off on a url basis:

In your web config use something like this:

```
<location path="my/long/route/">
    <system.webServer>
      <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" />
    </system.webServer> 
</location>
```

you are telling IIS to turn off dynamic compression for just that URL.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary assign to `dynamicCompressionBeforeCache` attribute a value equals to `false`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  …
  <system.webServer>
    …
    <httpCompression …>
      …
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression … dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    …
  </system.webServer>
  …
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you please explain why should it be false or is it specific to  WebMarkupMin?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue but the error solved when I used UseResponseCompression before UseStaticFiles

```
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
            OnPrepareResponse = context => context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=2592000")
        });
        app.UseWebMarkupMin();
```